# Why could a query take ages if run via sp_executesql (via an app) as opposed to a normal parameterized query on SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, timeout

So I have a query that's occasionally timing out in a C# web api application. It will start off fine and then at some point in the future it will start timing out and from then on time out unless something is done.

The query is constructed using Dapper and when I run a trace on the server I'm able to pick up the offending query it's turned into. If I run this as is on my machine (it uses exec.sp_executesql N'the query') it also takes ages to run. I give it to my colleague and for him it only takes 2 seconds to run. That's my first question, why would the same query execute significantly differently on different machines if they're still hitting the same server and database?

Secondly, if I take the text query and turn it into normal t-sql and run it, it again only takes 2 seconds. This leads me to my most likely cause but also question, is this a case of parameter sniffing causing performance hits?

I've tried running the exact same query as to what's caught by the trace and added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end and then it runs in 2 seconds. Previously, I was able to also clear the issue by rebuilding the indexes on the main table the query was using as they were getting badly fragmented. However, for the first time today that didn't work.

Comment: It sound like parameter sniffing to me. The query analyser cached a bad plan for your particular use. Do you have "Query Store" enabled. That helps identify bad plans and allows you evaluate and force specific plans per SP. Does Dapper send the request over wrapped as sp_executesql. I am not sure if OPTION RECOMPILE will work on that you would have to test it out as it might be seen as a separate batch statement than when you put the query in a SP or ssms.

Comment: @RossBush - what's Query Store? I tried the exact same query wrapped in sp_executesql with OPTION (RECOMPILE) and it worked. However, I thought if it was a bad cached plan then my colleague would have had the same issue when running it as me.

Comment: Your colleague  could have been running with different parameters or some event could have triggered a recompile before their command was executed. There is one other thing to consider. Was the database call wrapped in a transaction scope? If you or another developer were sitting on a breakpoint while in a tx then that could also explain this behavior.

Comment: @RossBush - my colleague ran it exactly as is (as in what we got from the trace). We did it within a few minutes of each other (mine first). After he said it ran fine for him I tried mine again and had the same issue again.As for the db call it's a standard dapper query.

Comment: SQL Server caches query plans based not only on the hash of the SQL statement but also on the current set of @@OPTIONS values. One of the most common causes of "It's slow in the app but fast in SSMS" is due to SSMS connecting with SET ARITHABORT ON but most other things connecting with SET ARITHABORT OFF. Have a read through [Query Processing Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide) for more insight to how all this works.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - thanks for the link. Reading it now. However, this isn't just a case of "It's slow in the app but fast in SSMS". My fault really for writing the title like that. If I take the exact query sql server is trying to execute (sp_executesql version) it runs very slowly for me on SSMS as well, but the exact same query runs fine for my colleague in SSMS. Equally, if I take the query and turn it into a standard t-sql query it also runs fine.

Comment: I have a question, in Oracle databases it is possible to find the Execution Plan, which is generated when a query is executed. Could you try to do the same in SQL Server? Catching the explain plan generated by your application to compare it against the one generated when the query is executed through SSSM.